# How to fix a strange indentation behaviour in Emacs sass-mode

Tags: emacs, sass

This issue ( https://github.com/nex3/sass-mode/issues/5  ) already explained what I want to say, please have a look at it. Is there any way to fix it.

> When I hit backspace, for instance after c-j, which always goes to one
>   level deeper instead of the same level, nothing happens except for the
>   control buffer giving the message "Mark set". When I check I see it's
>   bound to haml-electric-backspace. Thus the only two ways I can create
>   a new line and move my cursor to the same level of indentation as the
>   last line is ret tab tab or c-j followed by c-b c-b or tab tab. I
>   think c-j should default to the same level and that backspace should
>   have the default emacs behavior.

Comment: Please provide more details and ask an actual question  Think about link rot.

Comment: oh @puppybeard, thank you so much for your kind work.

Answer (score 3):

I found a bunch of bugs with sass-mode.

Here's some code I keep in my .emacs that might help:

```
(defconst sass-line-keywords
  '(("@\\(\\w+\\)"    0 font-lock-keyword-face sass-highlight-directive)
("/[/*].*"  0 font-lock-comment-face)
("[=+]\\w+" 0 font-lock-variable-name-face sass-highlight-script-after-match)
("!\\w+"    0 font-lock-variable-name-face sass-highlight-script-after-match)
(":\\w+"    0 font-lock-variable-name-face)
("\\w+\s*:" 0 font-lock-variable-name-face)
("\\(\\w+\\)\s*="  1 font-lock-variable-name-face sass-highlight-script-after-match)
("\\(:\\w+\\)\s*=" 1 font-lock-variable-name-face sass-highlight-script-after-match)
(".*"      sass-highlight-selector)))

(defconst sass-selector-font-lock-keywords
  '( ;; Attribute selectors (e.g. p[foo=bar])
("\\[\\([^]=]+\\)" (1 font-lock-variable-name-face)
 ("[~|$^*]?=\\([^]=]+\\)" nil nil (1 font-lock-string-face)))
("&"       0 font-lock-constant-face)
("\\.\\w+" 0 font-lock-type-face)
("#\\w+"   0 font-lock-keyword-face)
;; Pseudo-selectors, optionally with arguments (e.g. :first, :nth-child(12))
("\\(::?\\w+\\)" (1 font-lock-variable-name-face)
 ("(\\([^)]+\\))" nil nil (1 font-lock-string-face)))))
(defconst sass-non-block-openers
  '("^.*,$" ;; Continued selectors
"^ *@\\(extend\\|debug\\|warn\\|include\\|import\\)" ;; Single-line mixins
"^ *[$!]"     ;; Variables
".*[^\s-]+: [^\s-]" ;; a setting of some sort
))
```

I think the problem was particularly with sass-non-block-openers.  I'm sorry that I'm just dumping some code on you.  Hope this helps somehow anyway.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what any of that does, however having put it in my emacs config sass-mode now indents correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when finished, call RET, not C-j

backspace will step down level

everything okay AFAIS, no bug

Comment: I don't understand how you can get like this. i had installed both emacs 23.3 and 24.1, with sass-mode (require haml-mode, both installed by el-get) and no other third-party mode, but i always get bad result.